Customizing Yolo pre-trained Object Detection Model
I tried to customize the YoloV8 pre-trained object detection model on a custom dataset. I did some customization on Yolo's architecture, but after customizing the model it was unable to get a boundary box on detected objects. I don't know what caused it. I used this model to objects like trees, buildings and walls.And I used Google Colab as the training environment.
Is there anyone who customized the Yolo pre-trained object detection model on a custom dataset? Please let me know. Thank you.
